# How do I use Python in a Chrome extension?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension with Python. Is this possible or will I have to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) as that would let you write in Python but compile your code down to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not Directly. However there are some possibilities discussed here.
[NPAPI for Python - Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062444/npapi-for-python-chrome-extension)