# How do I execute python programs in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I have a python program and I need to call this code using JavaScript since I am using chrome extension.

So is there any way that we can call python code in java script and execute them i.e if I click the plug-in the manifest.json file should have an external command so that it calls python program and executes it and shows the desired output

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048436/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217042/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062444/.

Comment: are you wishing to call the python script via ajax?

Comment: man how many of these are you going to create...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/). It's a Python-to-Javascript compiler.