# Simple way to interecpt user entered URLs from Google Chrome in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have written a Python script that analyzes web URLs to warn the user if a URL that has been entered in a browser is a phishing website. I'm looking to implement this script somehow into Google Chrome. All the script needs to do is get the URL that a user has entered in Google Chrome. I am wondering if anyone can suggest a simple way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Google Chrome-specific, you could write a [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and utilize the [activeTab permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) (which allows you to read the URL bar).

The issue is that your program is written in python (chrome extensions are javascript), but there are possibilities such using a python-to-javascript compiler as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048436/chrome-extension-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062444/npapi-for-python-chrome-extension).

Comment: I found these articles as well: [1](https://pythonspot.com/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/) and [2](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-make-a-Google-Chrome-extension-using-Python)